# Liouville integrability

Tags: mathematical-physics

I am trying to understand how to use Liouville integrability to solve a question, but I could not understand how to calculate the functions $H_1,\ldots,H_n$ which are functionally independent (their wedge product is not equal to zero) and $\{H_j,H_k\}=0$ for all $j,k$ (the bracket is Poisson bracket) and each one is equal to the Hamiltonian

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well, they are the constants of motion, of course. But you will need to provide a lot more detail if you want to get a sensible answer. What exactly is your question? What is the problem that you're working on? What's the context where you encountered this problem? Etc.

Comment: I am trying to understand for the Hamiltonian H= \sum1/2 p^2_j - g^2\sum 1/(q^j-q^k)^2, j=1,...,n and j\leq k ,how we get H_1= trL , H_j=1/j tr L^j where L is matrix with diagonal p1,...,pn and the entries above the diagonal ig/(q^j-q^k)

Comment: Please edit the question to include the relevant details, and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make the formulas readable.